# Predicting Spirals

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, polygons, geometric-construction

I am currently in the process of analyzing a polyspiral, a spiral where each successive length drawn is increased at specified increment at the same angle.

*Please note the angles selected are the exterior angles or the angle by how much the turtle turns by.

144 degrees:

[image]

216 degrees:

[image: 2]]

versus 140 degrees

[image]

or 120 degrees:

[image]

Is there any way to predict the outcome (maybe the category or type of the spiral) of these spirals mathematically.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From a given starting point $(x,y)$, the next point will be given by $(x+r\cos\theta,y+r\sin\theta)$ where $r$ is the scaling factor and $\theta$ is the specified angle. In general, the $n$th vertex of the spiral would be given by $\bigg(x+r\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\cos(n\theta),y+r\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\sin(n\theta) \bigg)$.

Comment: Is there any way find the nth vertex without using a summation?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use complex variables:  define $z = x + iy$.  Then step $k$ shifts the turtle's location in the complex plane by $\Delta z = r(\cos(k\theta) + i \sin(k \theta)) = e^{ik\theta}$, and the total sum of all these displacements is the geometric series $r \sum_{k=0}^n e^{i k \theta} = r (1 - e^{i(n+1)\theta})/(1 - e^{i\theta}).$  Take the real and imaginary parts of this to get the final $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: Note also that if $r$ is changing linearly with each step, you have an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence), for which there is also a closed-form expression for the sum of the $n+1$ terms.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you turn by an angle $\theta$ each time, and you find that after you've made $m$ such terms, you end up facing in the same direction you started at.  Then it must be the case that you've turned some integer number $n$ of full rotations, which means that
$$
360 n = \theta m
$$
(with $\theta$ measured in degrees.)  Moreover, the number of "points" on your design will be the *smallest* integer $m$ for which this is the case.  This implies that
$$
360 n = \theta m = \text{lcm} (\theta, 360),
$$
where "lcm" is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $\theta$ (in degrees) and 360.

So, taking your examples in turn:

- For $\theta = 144$, we have $5 \times 144 = 2 \times 360$.  So you get a five-pointed star.
- For $\theta = 216$, we have $5 \times 216 = 3 \times 360$.  So you get a five-pointed star again.
- For $\theta = 140$, we have $18 \times 140 = 7 \times 360$.  So you get an 18-pointed star.
- For $\theta = 120$, we have $3 \times 120 = 1 \times 360$.  So you get a three-pointed "star" (otherwise known as a triangle).

Note that so long as you only use integer numbers of degrees, it must be the case that the number of "points" of the star will be a divisor of 360.