# Predicting The Result of Spirals

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I am in the process of studying spirals, where each successive length drawn is the same but every angle is increased at a certain increment.

*Please note the angles selected are the exterior angles or the angle by how much the turtle turns by.

Angle 189, Increment 1

[image: Increment 1]

If the angle is 25 and the increment is 2:

[image: Angle 25, Increment 2]

Angle 180, Increment 7

[image: Angle 180, Increment 7]

There are many other unusual looking spirals you can observe changing the angle and increment especially ones similar to the first spiral shown with increment 1 and angle 189, like increment 5 and angle 200 or increment 10 and angle 50 will also generate spirals with 2 nodes or "attractors."

Is there any way to predict how many nodes- or "attractors" there will be in a spiral based on its angle and increment value? Also, for any starting point (x,y), is there any way to find the nth vertex of the spiral.

Help would be much appreciated. I would love this type of results or answers: [Predicting Spirals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687287/predicting-spirals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, each S-shaped thing between two "attractors" is just a discrete approximation of a [Cornu spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral). The straight sections are where your relative angle passes through 0 (or a multiple of $360^\circ$, which is essentially the same), and the angle between those is the difference in the *absolute* angle accumulated while the relative angle went in steps from $0^\circ$ to $360^\circ$. Again, as long as you only use integer numbers of degrees, the pattern must be eventually periodic, but the period may turn out to be pretty long (especially for those steps which are not divisors of 360).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for odd-numbered increments that are not factors of 360 (like increment 21 and angle 3).

Comment: Well, I would expect this to produce two "branches" with 7 "attractors" on each; is this not so? On a side note, who removed my earlier comments?

Comment: There's a total of 8 attractors for that increment+angle, if I did everything correctly.